# How to write Rewrite rule for my Query?

Tags: .htaccess

I have getting problem in htaccess rewrite rule.

> My current url is:-
>
> http://example.com/abc/blogs/blogs/xyz/
>
> I want to convert this url to:-
>
> http://example.com/abc/blogs/xyz/

How can I write Rewrite rules in my .htaccess file??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule on top of your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?/blogs)/blogs/(.*)$ $1/$2 [L,NC]
```

Comment: On my testing it redirects `http://localhost/abc/blogs/blogs/xyz/` to `http://localhost/abc/blogs/xyz/`. What URL did you enter to test?

Comment: In my testing `localhost/Nice/blogs/blogs/the-evolution-of-video-analytics-2/`  got redirected to `localhost/Nice/blogs/the-evolution-of-video-analytics-2/` You would have paced in wrong htaccess

Comment: Now Its working but it redirect to that url but I don't want to redirect.. I just want to change the url with same page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88759/discussion-between-sonia-sarangal-and-anubhava).

Comment: May be you some other rules or some CMS/PHP framework that doesn't like internal rewrites.